# bundle install returns "Could not locate Gemfile"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, installation, bundle, gemfile

I'm new to Rails and am currently working through a guide. 
The guide states:

> Use a text editor to update the Gemfile needed by Bundler with the
>   contents of Listing 2.1.
>
> ```
> source 'https://rubygems.org'
>
> gem 'rails', '3.2.3'
>
> group :development do
>   gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'
> end
>
>
> # Gems used only for assets and not required
> # in production environments by default.
>
> group :assets do
>   gem 'sass-rails',   '3.2.4'
>   gem 'coffee-rails', '3.2.2'
>   gem 'uglifier', '1.2.3'
> end
>
> gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.0'
>
> group :production do
>   gem 'pg', '0.12.2'
> end
> ```
>
> We then install and include the gems using the `bundle install`
>     command:
>
> ```
>     $ bundle install --without production
> ```
>
> If Bundler complains about `no such file to load -- readline
>   (LoadError)` try adding `gem ’rb-readline’` to your Gemfile.)

I followed the steps even adding on `gem 'rb-readline'` to the `Gemfile`, but apparently the file can't be found and when I go to my text editor I do see the `Gemfile` itself. I noticed that they made me put `gem 'rails', 3.2.3` and my version of Rails is 3.2.1 so I tried changing it to 3.2.1 but that didn't work either.

Any thoughts or advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: why you put `- - ` chars in Gemfile listing?

Comment: i found the solution to the problem.. i'm suppose to "$cd demo_app" and then "$install bundle" from that folder location. :)

Comment: This solved it for me: https://jekyllrb.com/docs/.

Answer (score 291, accepted):

You just need to change directories to your app, THEN run `bundle install` :)

Comment: @svoisen, :D Google includes your answer in the snippet when searching this particular problem, btw. Cheers and thanks from the sleep-deprived future!

Comment: BTW you can find your app directory by using the `whereis <app_name>` command, ussualy the Gemfile is under /usr/shared/*

Comment: App could also be in a folder in /opt/

Comment: Just add some clearance that move to the project folder, not 'bin' folder of the project :)

Answer (score 24):

You may also indicate the path to the gemfile in the same command e.g.

```
BUNDLE_GEMFILE="MyProject/Gemfile.ios" bundle install
```

Comment: Perfect answer. Because in my situation I can't get access bundle command in everywhere. `[root@alc bin]# BUNDLE_GEMFILE="../../apps/redmine/htdocs/Gemfile" ./bundle install` is my command to execute.

Comment: For some reason I was having this issue when I was copying a Gemfile into a docker container, I couldnt find a .bundle and I had set my WOKRDIR but it didnt seem to catch it for bundle install, this did the trick!

Answer (score 22):

**I had this problem as well on an OSX machine. I discovered that rails was not installed... which surprised me as I thought OSX always came with Rails. 
To install rails**

- `sudo gem install rails`
- **to install jekyll I also needed sudo**
- `sudo gem install jekyll bundler`
- `cd ~/Sites`
- `jekyll new <foldername>`
- `cd <foldername>` **OR** `cd !$` **(that is magic ;)**
- `bundle install`
- `bundle exec jekyll serve`
- **Then in your browser just go to** http://127.0.0.1:4000/ **and it really should be running**

Comment: Avoid using `sudo` to install gems. This will cause you pain. Read more: https://thoughtbot.com/blog/psa-do-not-use-system-ruby

Answer (score 15):

You must be in the same directory of `Gemfile`

Answer (score 10):

I had this problem on Ubuntu 18.04. I updated the gem

```bash
sudo gem install rails
sudo gem install jekyll
sudo gem install jekyll bundler
cd ~/desiredFolder
jekyll new <foldername>
cd <foldername> OR 
bundle init
bundle install
bundle add jekyll
bundle exec jekyll serve
```

All worked and goto your browser just go to http://127.0.0.1:4000/ and it really should be running

Answer (score 8):

When I had similar problem `gem update --system` helped me. Run this before `bundle install`

Answer (score 3):

In my case this worked:

- `cd /usr/bin`
- `touch Gemfile`
- Now you can then run `bundle install`.

Comment: `touch Gemfile` returned: `touch: Gemfile: Operation not permitted`

Comment: `tocuh Gemfile` returned: `touch: Gemfile: Read-only file system`

Answer (score 2):

1. Make sure that the file name is Capitalized `Gemfile` instead of `gemfile`.
2. Make sure you're in the same directory as the `Gemfile`.

Answer (score 0):

You may run the following code, assuming you don't have any gem file, it means you don't have Jekyll project:

- Initialize bundle in the main project folder:

  `bundle init`
- Install bundle:

  `bundle install`
- Add Jekyll to the project:

  `bundle add jekyll`
- Run your application as the command below with live reload:

  `jekyll serve --livereload`

Hope it helps!

With <3 by Daniel Fernandes

Answer (score -1):

Search for the Gemfile file in your project,  go to that directory and then run "bundle install". prior to running this command make sure you have installed the gem "sudo gem install bundler"

Comment: he did a "bundle install", i don't understand your answer

Answer (score -15):

Think more about what you are installing and navigate Gemfile folder, then try using `sudo bundle install`

Comment: you should never run bundle with sudo