# connecting with yaml in ruby application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yaml

I'm trying to build a small application with ruby.

I'm learning to setup the database connecting with sequel in following a Tuts+ course. 
However, after I finish editing the connection file like I've learned in the the lesson the terminal gives me this message:

```
/Users/ALROQEE/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/bundler-1.7.2/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:24:in `default_gemfile': Could not locate Gemfile (Bundler::GemfileNotFound)
    from /Users/ALROQEE/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/bundler-1.7.2/lib/bundler.rb:249:in `default_gemfile'
    from /Users/ALROQEE/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/bundler-1.7.2/lib/bundler.rb:193:in `root'
    from /Users/ALROQEE/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/bundler-1.7.2/lib/bundler.rb:100:in `bundle_path'
    from /Users/ALROQEE/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/bundler-1.7.2/lib/bundler.rb:401:in `configure_gem_home_and_path'
    from /Users/ALROQEE/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/bundler-1.7.2/lib/bundler.rb:91:in `configure'
    from /Users/ALROQEE/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/bundler-1.7.2/lib/bundler.rb:152:in `definition'
    from /Users/ALROQEE/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/bundler-1.7.2/lib/bundler.rb:117:in `setup'
    from /Users/ALROQEE/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/bundler-1.7.2/lib/bundler.rb:133:in `require
```

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: What directory are you in when you run `bundle install`?

Comment: thanks for replay , actually i don't know ! how can i know about that

Answer (score 0):

Your probably running the command from the wrong directory.

Below has a similar issue,

[bundle install returns "Could not locate Gemfile"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10012181/bundle-install-could-not-locate-gemfile)

The error means it cannot locate the file entitled 'Gemfile'. If you need anymore help I would recommended posting the link to the tutorial for more context.

Comment: thank for very much for your answer , please give the tutorial link if you can , i'am still having this problem