# Error with bundle install on Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, bundle-install

I'm trying to install Ruby on Rails on Windows using [this tutorial](http://nlb-creations.com/2013/06/26/installing-ruby-on-rails-and-redmine-with-xampp-on-windows-7/).

I successfully finished all the steps until step 13:

> Run `bundle install` again

This is what I'm getting:

```
C:\Users\user1>gem install rmagick --platform=ruby -- --with-opt-dir=C:\RailsIns
taller\ImageMagick
Fetching: rmagick-2.13.3.gem (100%)
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Please report any bugs. See https://github.com/gemhome/rmagick/compare/RMagick_2
-13-2...master and https://github.com/rmagick/rmagick/issues/18
Successfully installed rmagick-2.13.3
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for rmagick-2.13.3...
Installing RDoc documentation for rmagick-2.13.3...

C:\Users\user1>bundle install
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Co
uld not find bundler (>= 0) amongst [bigdecimal-1.1.0, io-console-0.3, json-1.5.
5, minitest-2.5.1, rake-0.9.2.2, rdoc-3.9.5, rmagick-2.13.3] (Gem::LoadError)
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in `
to_spec'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1231:in `gem'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/bin/bundle:22:in `<main>'
```

What could be the problem?

### Update:

After running `gem install bundler`:

```
C:\Users\user1>gem list bundler

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bundler (1.7.7)

C:\Users\user1>bundle install
Could not locate Gemfile
```

Comment: Did you set your path like so: 
`set CPATH=C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.7.7-Q16\include` and
`set LIBRARY_PATH=C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.7.7-Q16\lib` This was taken from an earlier answer to one of your questions.

Comment: Yes I did:
C:\Users\user1>set CPATH=C:\RailsInstaller\ImageMagick\include

C:\Users\user1>set LIBRARY_PATH=C:\RailsInstaller\ImageMagick\lib

Comment: `gem install bundler`?

Comment: C:\Users\user1>gem install bundler
Fetching: bundler-1.7.7.gem (100%)
Successfully installed bundler-1.7.7
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for bundler-1.7.7...
Installing RDoc documentation for bundler-1.7.7...

C:\Users\user1>bundle install
Could not locate Gemfile

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problems thanks to this:

[bundle install returns "Could not locate Gemfile"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10012181/bundle-install-could-not-locate-gemfile)

```
C:\Users\user1>cd C:/xampp/htdocs/dev-ruby/redmine

C:\xampp\htdocs\dev-ruby\redmine>bundle install
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check if bundler is installed by using  `$gem list bundler` or even `$which bundle`

If nothing is shown, then install bundler by typing `gem install bundler`

After that try `bundle install`

Answer (score 0):

You need to install rmagic library on your window system.

Please follow blow link for more info.

http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_install_rmagick_gem_on_Windows